# can't the function code block access variables in razor code block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have initialize some variables in the Razor code block at the top of the page as follow:

```
@{    
    var name=string.Empty;
    var email=string.Empty;
    var subject=string.Empty;
    var message=string.Empty;

    SetupValidation();
    HandlePostRequest();
}
```

At the bottom of the page (after html tags...etc) I created some functions:

```
@functions
{
    protected void HandlePostRequest()
    {
        if(IsPost)
        {
            name=Request[Fields.Name];
            email=Request[Fields.Email];
            subject=Request[Fields.Subject];
            message=Request[Fields.Message];

            if(Validation.IsValid())
            {
                using (var rep=new ContactLogRepository("usingClassCode"))
                {
                    rep.Insert(name, email, subject, message);
                }
                Response.Redirect("success.cshtml");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

But seems to me that the function can't access the variables above because I am getting this error:

> "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'name' does not exist in the
>   current context"

But I can't know the reason, I watched an Online video and it was completely working in it!! does anyone have explanation for this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the variables in the function because they are in a different scope to the variables declared in the block at the top.

Try this:

```
@functions
{
    protected void HandlePostRequest()
    {
        if(IsPost)
        {
            var name = Request[Fields.Name];
            var email = Request[Fields.Email];
            var subject = Request[Fields.Subject];
            var message = Request[Fields.Message];

            if(Validation.IsValid())
            {
                using (var rep=new ContactLogRepository("usingClassCode"))
                {
                    rep.Insert(name, email, subject, message);
                }
                Response.Redirect("success.cshtml");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```